# Type conversions and if expressions

Tags: ada, ada2012

In [this](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rat/html/Rat12-3-2.html#:%7E:text=If%20the%20conditional%20expression%20is%20the%20argument%20of%20a%20type%20conversion:%7E:text=If%20the%20conditional%20expression%20is%20the%20argument%20of%20a%20type%20conversion) page, John Barnes writes:

> If the conditional expression is the argument of a type conversion then effectively the conversion is considered pushed down to the dependent expressions. Thus
>
> `X := Float(if P then A else B);`
>
> is equivalent to
>
> `X := (if P then Float(A) else Float(B));`

So why can't I compile the following program under GNAT 10.3.0?

```
procedure Main is
   P : Boolean := True;
   X : Float;
begin
   X := Float (if P then 0.5 else 32);
end Main;
```

```
Compile
   [Ada]          main.adb
main.adb:5:35: expected a real type
main.adb:5:35: found type universal integer
gprbuild: *** compilation phase failed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you’ve found a long-standing error in the compiler! (same behaviour in GCC 12.1.0).

John Barnes’ justification is at [AARM 4.5.7(10ff)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/aarm12_w_tc1/html/AA-4-5-7.html#p10).

---

*thanks for providing real code and the error messages!*